# How to get a property name and its value using Swift 2.0, and reflection?

Tags: reflection, swift2

Given this Model:

```
public class RSS2Feed {

    public var channel: RSS2FeedChannel?

    public init() {}
}

public class RSS2FeedChannel {   

    public var title: String?
    public var description: String?

    public init() {}

}
```

What would I need to do in order to get the property names and values of an `RSS2FeedChannel` instance?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
let feed = RSS2Feed()
feed.channel = RSS2FeedChannel()
feed.channel?.title = "The Channel Title"

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: feed.channel)
mirror.children.first // ({Some "Some"}, {{Some "The Channel Title...

for (index, value) in mirror.children.enumerate() {
    index // 0
    value.label // "Some"
    value.value // RSS2FeedChannel
}
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a `Dictionary` that matches the instance, using reflection, but so far I'm unable to get the properties name and values of the instance.

Documentation says that:

> The optional label may be used when appropriate, e.g. to represent the name of a stored property or of an active enum case, and will be used for lookup when Strings are passed to the descendant method.

Yet I only get a "Some" string.

Also, the value property is returning a string with the Type `RSS2FeedChannel` when I would expect each children to be "An element of the reflected instance's structure."!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When i understand correct this should solve ur problem:

```
func aMethod() -> Void {
    let feed = RSS2Feed()
    feed.channel = RSS2FeedChannel()
    feed.channel?.title = "The Channel Title"
//  feed.channel?.description = "the description of your channel"

    guard  let channel = feed.channel else {
        return
    }

    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: channel)
    for child in mirror.children {
        guard let key = child.label else {
            continue
        }
        let value = child.value

        guard let result = self.unwrap(value) else {
            continue
        }

        print("\(key): \(result)")
    }
}

private func unwrap(subject: Any) -> Any? {
    var value: Any?
    let mirrored = Mirror(reflecting:subject)
    if mirrored.displayStyle != .Optional {
        value = subject
    } else if let firstChild = mirrored.children.first {
        value = firstChild.value
    }
    return value
}
```

just some little changes for swift 3:

```
private func unwrap(_ subject: Any) -> Any? {
    var value: Any?
    let mirrored = Mirror(reflecting:subject)
    if mirrored.displayStyle != .optional {
        value = subject
    } else if let firstChild = mirrored.children.first {
        value = firstChild.value
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `descendent` method on the Mirror object to get this information. It will return nil if the values aren't found or the optionals contain no value.

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: feed.channel)
let child1 = mirror.descendant("Some", "title") // "The Channel Title"

// or on one line
let child3 = Mirror(reflecting: feed).descendant("channel", "Some", "title")
```

Comment: I'm finding that the value of child1, when the optional contains no value is not simply `nil`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773928/how-to-get-a-property-name-and-its-value-using-swift-2-0-and-reflection